# Why a signal is not being processed in receiving thread if the signalling thread is blocked?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

This is gets called in `thread A`:

```
void MainApplication::notify()
{
    emit mySignal();
    QThread::currentThread()->sleep(5);
}
```

Before this the connection and receiver creation happens happens:

```
// thread A
void MainApplication::init()
{
    receiver->moveToThread(threadB);

    connect(this,
            &MainApplication::mySignal,
            receiver,
            &Receiver::onMySignal,
            Qt::QueuedConnection);
}
```

Expectation: slot `Receiver::onMySignal()` gets called on `thread B`.
Reality: slot doesn't get called while emitting `thread A` sleeps.

P.S.: I'm 100% sure that the event loop of `thread B` is running when the signal emitted.

Comment: I'm guessing the signal is only send when control is returned to the event loop of the signalling thread, not directly when you call emit, since it's a queued connection.

Comment: @xander This is my only guess also, but I couldn't find a prove and workaround.

Comment: Is the return value of `renderManager.data()` the same as `receiver`?

Comment: Your code looks strange.. Does `renderManager.data()` return the object `receiver`?

Comment: @thuga Yes, this is receiver. I copy pasted and didn't change this line. Updated the example.

Comment: @xander: **that is not the case**. Signals are sent immediately. The invocation of the _slot_ is queued (requires event loop running in the receiver's object thread).

Comment: Tried your question with a simple example and it works as expected. So you have something wrong in your code that makes your case more specific. To specify `Qt::QueuedConnection` is useless btw, it will be queued because you are using two different threads, and auto is always more robust in case of future changes in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it should be. The following simple example works fine.

```
class SenderObj : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void happened();
public:
    void triggerSignal() {
        qDebug() << "Emitting 'happened'";
        emit happened();
        qDebug() << "Emitted 'happened'";
        QThread::currentThread()->sleep(5);
    }
};

class ReceiverObj : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void doSomething() {
        qDebug() << "SLOT called in " << QThread::currentThread();
    }
};

// In my MainWindow :
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    auto thread = new QThread(this);
    thread->start();

    m_senderObj = new SenderObj;
    m_receiverObj = new ReceiverObj;

    m_receiverObj->moveToThread(thread);
    connect(m_senderObj, &SenderObj::happened, m_receiverObj, &ReceiverObj::doSomething);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    m_senderObj->triggerSignal();
}
```

When I click the push-button the signal is emitted immediately, the second thread executes the slot right away, and my main-thread (the MainWindow) is frozen for 5s.

Comment: Thank you, you're right - I couldn't reproduce the issue on minimalistic example as well. After careful codebase investigation I found the problem and it doesn't related to signals and threads.

Answer (score 1):

To get this handled you need to run the event-queue once by calling

```
QCoreApplication::processEvents();
```

This will trigger to handling of all enqueued events from your threads.

Comment: Thank you. That did the job.

Comment: Sorry, I have to mark the question as un-answered. As it turned out a single call to `processEvents()` doesn't fix the problem (see [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47221878/why-do-i-need-to-call-qcoreapplicationprocessevents-multiple-times-in-orde))